# iOS select image from cloud storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2

The user should be allowed to select an image from more than just their device.

Countless services provide this functionality, Slack is a great example. Is there a library that can assist in this as my searching has turned up blank.

[image: screen shot]

I really don't mind if it's in Objective C or Swift.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right forum for this type of question, but I can't really recommend a better one. That being said, it shouldn't be too difficult to build something like this using the individual SDKs from these services. I've used the Dropbox SDK before and remember it being pretty straightforward.

Comment: That was my first thought but I've seen this type of thing in many places that I thought someone had already beat me to it, in trying to avoid recreating the wheel I came here for advice. The fact that there are icons in the menu make me think it's an Apple SDK because the only way to access the image view in each action sheet option is via KVC

Comment: Hmm... good point. Have you looked at `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

Comment: I hadn't seen that class before. Will investigate if it's a likely suspect. Cheers

Comment: Found it. It's `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, the library used to generate the action sheet included in the image you attached is a native iOS library / class called `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13505634)

Comment: @abarisone I have edited my answer to be a bit more clear, but it does answer the question. OP is asking for the name of the library that performs this function. `UIDocumentMenuViewController` is that library.

Comment: Cheers. That's the one. Don't know why I got downvoted though, genuine question and no idea of the class. Once I had the class name I found countless sources of help. Thanks anyway :)